# AzureCognitive R package translate service returns http 400: "body of request is not valid JSON."

Tags: r, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I've tried to get the translate service to work using the [AzureCognitive](https://github.com/Azure/AzureCognitive) R package, but I get a HTTP 400 error and I can't seem to fix it.

```
# Initial setup
# I've already did the create login
# az <- AzureRMR::create_azure_login(tenant = "<tenant>")

az <- AzureRMR::get_azure_login()
sub <- az$get_subscription(id = "<id>")
rg <- sub$get_resource_group("<resource-group>")

# retrieve it
cogsvc <- rg$get_cognitive_service(name = "<name>")

# getting the endpoint from the resource object
endp <- cogsvc$get_endpoint()


############################
# This is where it fails
############################

call_cognitive_endpoint(endpoint = endp,
                        operation = "translate",
                        options = list('api-version' = "3.0",
                                       'from' = 'en',
                                       'to' = 'dk'),
                        body = "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]",
                        http_verb = "POST")


call_cognitive_endpoint(endpoint = endp,
                        operation = "translate",
                        options = list('api-version' = "3.0",
                                       'from' = 'en',
                                       'to' = 'dk'),
                        body = list(text = "Hello, what is your name"),
                        http_verb = "POST")
```

Can someone see if this is a bug or me doing something wrong?

Comment: You can refer to [REST API Post Error: The body of the request is not valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194632/rest-api-post-error-the-body-of-the-request-is-not-valid-json) and [Common REST API error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes)

Comment: In this [example](https://github.com/Azure/AzureCognitive/blob/59a2c369690d2811865032163e468cf0d0b061e6/tests/testthat/test02_cogsvc_token.R), body is passed as `body=list(list(Text="Hello world")),`

Comment: Excellent @DeepDave-MT. Do you want to answer? This works: `call_cognitive_endpoint(endpoint = endp, operation = "translate", options = list('api-version' = "3.0", 'from' = 'en', 'to' = 'da'),body = list(list(text = 'Hello, what is your name')), http_verb = "POST")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [example](https://github.com/Azure/AzureCognitive/blob/59a2c369690d2811865032163e468cf0d0b061e6/tests/testthat/test02_cogsvc_token.R), you can pass the body as `body=list(list(text = "Hello, what is your name"")),`

```
call_cognitive_endpoint(endpoint = endp,
                        operation = "translate",
                        options = list('api-version' = "3.0",
                                       'from' = 'en',
                                       'to' = 'dk'),
                        body = list(list(text = "Hello, what is your name")),
                        http_verb = "POST")
```